# Dynamic dropdown list not loading in modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dependent dynamic drop  listing that works fine but as soon as I include it inside a modal, it doesn't work.

This is my code within the modal:

```
<script src="plugins/jQuery/2.1.1.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#BugMaster').on('change',function(){
        var bugmasterID = $(this).val();
        if(bugmasterID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajax/bugs/populate.cat.php',
                data:'id_bug_master='+bugmasterID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#BugMasterCat').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#BugMasterCat').html('<option value="">Select BugMaster first</option>');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This is the html part of the form with the list :

```
<select class="form-control" name="BugMaster" id="BugMaster">
 <option value="0" selected="selected">Please select module</option>
   <?
    while($r_b_c = mysqli_fetch_array($q_b_c)){
   ?>
  <option value="<? echo $r_b_c['id_bug_master']; ?>"><? echo $r_b_c['name']; ?>
  </option>
 <? } ?>
 </select>
```

This is the dependent list

```
<select name="BugMasterCat" id="BugMasterCat">
 <option value="">Select country first</option>
</select>
```

The 'populate.cat.php' file looks like this:

```
if(isset($_POST["id_bug_master"]) && !empty($_POST["id_bug_master"])){

  $id_bug_master = clean_data($_POST['id_bug_master']);

   $q_cat = mysqli_query($sqllink,"SELECT * FROM bugs_categories
    WHERE valid='1' AND id_bug_master='$id_bug_master'");

    while($r_cat = mysqli_fetch_array($q_cat)){
        echo "<option value='$r_cat[id_cat]'>$r_cat[name]</option>";
    }
}
```

Then again, all this works fine if I load it directly from a page, but as soon as I open it in a modal, it fails and no categories are shown. I'm thinking it has to do with $(document).ready(function() that is not loading.

By not working I mean that the second drop down list is not being loaded.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think no event is attached to your drop down

change your code:

... $('#BugMaster').on('change',function(){ ....

with

$(document).on('click', '#BugMaster', function() {

Comment: I just tried, but the second list is still not being created,
$(document).ready(function(){
    //$('#BugMaster').on('change',function(){
 $(document).on('click', '#BugMaster', function() {

Comment: I think you made a mistake plz show me what did you try (js code)

Answer (score 0):

You need to load your JAVASCRIPT code from model itself, not from the parent / Base page.

But if you want to use another option that either use delegate or use inline javascript function call.

```
$(document).delegate('#BugMaster', 'change', function(){
    //Implement your code here
});

                            OR 

<select class="form-control" name="BugMaster" id="BugMaster" onchange="CALLJAVASCRIPTFUNCTIONHERE();">
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but the list is still not being populated from the modal...

Comment: Have you tried all three options suggested by me, 1) To include js code in popup html, 2) delegate ?